# Как выводить числа без e?

Tags: c#

Есть программа, она может выдать и нормальные значения (10.10 к примеру), а может и "корявые". К примеру, 3.333333e что-то типа такого. Нужно сделать проверку на вот эту "e", чтобы в результат не выдавались те числа, в которых присутствует "e".

Comment: e присутсвует не в числе, а в формате его вывода. Поменяйте формат вывода числе там, где его выводите

Comment: "корявые" - это экспоненциальная запись числа. Так у вас задача "не генерировать (слишком маленькие числа)" или "генерировать, но при выводе показывать в нормальном виде с кучей нулей"?

Comment: Используйте `.ToString("0.#########################")`

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/14964737/6766879

Answer (score 6):

По умолчанию при преобразовании числа в строку (а для вывода его на экран это обязательно) выбирается кратчайшая запись между обычной (как вы привыкли со времен школы) и экспоненциальной. Чтобы изменить это поведение, вам придется указать формат явно.

Для того чтобы форматтер отбрасывал незначащие цифры, используйте заместитель цифры `#`:

```
var x = 0.00001 / Math.PI;
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("0.#########################"));
// 3,18309886183791E-06
// 0,00000318309886183791
```

Если вы не знаете заранее каких минимальных значений могут достигать ваши числа, можно написать что-то вроде:

```
public static readonly string doubleSchoolFormat = "0." + new string('#', 324);

...
var x = 1E-300 / Math.PI;
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString(doubleSchoolFormat));
// 3,18309886183791E-301
// 0,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000318309886183791
```

[Строки настраиваемых числовых форматов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)
[double (справочник по C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double)